# How do I turn off the HTC Desire boot jingle?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, reboot

Even with a set of headphones plugged in, when I reboot my HTC Desire it (ironically) still plays the 'quietly brilliant' boot screen jingle loudly on the built-in speaker.

This can be utterly annoying when lying in bed and the handset needs a reboot as it invariably wakes up the wife.

Can this be turned off or replaced?

Answer (score 3):

There's an app for, well, turning off the sound on shutdown and then back on at startup.  As I've got Tasker I no longer use it, but you're looking for *Silent Boot* by Anton Weber.

Comment: With Silent Boot I still can hear a very short part of the shutdown jingle (maybe a couple of micro seconds before Silent Boot can deactivate the sound). Tasker has a little longer and the first three notes of the sound are played before it is muted. I'm a Tasker newbie and used "Silent Mode On" for the "Device Shutdown" event. Is there a more optimal way do do this?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found to silence it was to have the phone on vibrate when it reboots.  Doesn't seem to play any sounds when it comes back up then.

Comment: Setting to "Silent mode" will also have this effect.